# When google calendar v3 API was officially release?

Tags: api, date, calendar, release

Please some one tell me what is the release date of calendar v3 API

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software history and not programming as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the precise release date of v3, but the deprecation of v2 was Novermber 17th, 2014.  So you could consider November 17th to be the official v3 enforcement date.